# Internet Explorer issue holding a $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, session

I know there is heaps of this on the internet and i have tried things like use cookies (didnt work) check for blank anchors like  and i have none of them. Microsoft is terrible i think we can all agree!

On safari, chrome and firefox etc (the good browsers) the code works fine and logs the user in. I am assuming the problem is resting with the session or cookie data because if you type in a wrong username/password on the website it comes up with an error saying its invalid (on internet ex).

The code where i am setting the session and cookies is this:

```
       session_start();

    $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

So this should work fine should it not? Thank you for taking time to read this.

Quick edit: I also have a facebook login button and this section of code is if the account is linked (it still involves $_SESSION):

```
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($SrcUser)) 
            { 
                 $id = $row["id"];
                 $user_level = $row["user_level"];
            }

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
    mysql_query("update `users` 
        set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= '', `online`='0' 
        where `id`='$_SESSION[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());


        // Javascript redirect.. its kinda cheating to be honest as if i dont use it i will have awkwardness with header errors
        ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "myaccount.php"
        </script>
```

Comment: `i dont use it i will have awkwardness with header errors` So you're sending some output? That would interfere with cookies,as they use headers too. And what does serverside $_SESSIONs (apart from the SSID) have to do with IE? It might be me but I can't understand the issue, sorry

Comment: @DamienPirsy using header wont work as im sending over information to the page before the header so it will throw errors left right and center. I dont know what the $_SESSION has to do with IE but i have seen a lot on the internet about it and its the only thing i can think that could cause it not to continue

Comment: If you send output before headers I see a flow there. Are you sure you absolutetly need to do that? Can't it be worked around with buffering?

Comment: Yeah i looked into that, couldnt really understand it

Answer (score 1):

Trying adding the following to the header of the response

```
header( 'P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"' );
```

if that doesn't work try this

```
header ( 'P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"' );
```

[more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this; I added it just above the session start. I get a white page of death on myaccount.php so it moved forward however i get a white page of death. Did i put it in the right place?

Comment: it needs to be done before anything is output (via echo, print, etc); ideally, put it right at the top of the very first php script that is loaded

Comment: i have put it at the top and still white page of death :-/